# tsql substring or string manipulation

Tags: string, t-sql, substring

i have an nvarchar(max) column and i need to extract everything between the opening a href tags and the closing a href tag.  for example if the contents of my column where the following:

```
Here you can visit <a href="http://www.thisite.com">this link</a> or this
<a href="http://www.newsite.com">new link</a>. this is just a test to find the right answer.
```

then my results of my query should be:

```
"<a href="http://www.thisite.com">this link</a>"
"<a href="http://www.newsite.com">new link</a>"
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CLR User-defined function (supported in Sql Server 2005+):

[Regular Expressions Make Pattern Matching And Data Extraction Easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

Comment: I agree on the use of the CLR for this but regexes can't be used *reliably* to parse html. For a good read on that, take a look at [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)... *The <center> cannot hold*

Comment: *HTML is a language of sufficient complexity that it cannot be parsed by regular expressions. Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions*

Comment: I agree, but author is not required to **parse HTML**. Since the problem is simple “to extract everything between the opening a href tags and the closing a href tag” - KISS principle should work just fine here.

Comment: I don't know the difference between parsing and extracting but for this case, regexes might be sufficient. I just wanted to *warn* OP about possible problems he *might* encounter using regexes. Note that writing a decent regex can be quite tricky and if OP is going to use the CLR, afaik .NET already provides libraries that can parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a varchar(max) = 'Here you can visit <a href="http://www.thisite.com">this link</a> or this <a href="http://www.newsite.com">new link</a>. this is just a test to find the right answer. '

;with cte as
(
select cast(1 as bigint) f, cast(1 as bigint) t 
union all 
select charindex('<a href=', @a, t), charindex('</a>', @a, charindex('<a href=', @a, t)) 
from cte where charindex('<a href=', @a, t) > 0
)
select substring(@a, f, t-f)+'</a>' from cte
where t > 1
```